# PassOptionsToPackage Order / priority (solving a package class)

Tags: packages

I use the teach package (which isn't on ctan but can be downloaded [here](https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/teachV1-4.zip)).

My document was first :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
\usepackage[]{teach} 

\begin{document}

dsgsgsd

\end{document}
```

But it ended with the following error :

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.
```

Which was triggered by the teach package using geometry package with parameter :

```
% THIS CODE IS IN TEACH PACKAGE SOURCE
\RequirePackage[%
            hmargin=2.5cm,
            vmargin=2cm
            %,showframe,showcrop
            ]{geometry}
```

I found a solution with the `\PassOptionsToPackage` command :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}{geometry}
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[]{teach} 

\begin{document}

dsgsgsd

\end{document}
```

I no longer have the error but the margin are wrong (it use the margins defined by teach instead of mine).

I suggest it's because PassOptionsToPackage have lower priority than the ones called by the teach package.

How can I solve my issue ?

Comment: Because I have not that package `teach` I can not test, but have you simply tried to move line `\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}` **after calling package `teach`? Do you see that an MWE is important for us to be able to test given code on your own computers to find errors like that you have?

Comment: Yes I tried moving the \geometry line after calling package teach but I still get the error.

I have given MWE, but it's just that the teach package is missing. It can be downloaded here : https://www.mathweb.fr/euclide/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/teachV1-4.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving

```
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
```

after

```
\usepackage[]{teach}
```

and deleting

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Works so my problem is fixed.

But if someone know a general solution about this (i.e. make `\PassOptionsToPackage` have priority) please answer this might be usefull in the future to me or someone else.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[]{teach} 
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}


\begin{document}

dsgsgsd

\end{document}
```